# What's the meaning of independent variables

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help to understand the meaning of independent variables in this context:

[image]

What I know is an element of $k[x,y]$ is for example $x^2+y$, but I couldn't understand what's the meaning of "independent variables". The author does mean that for any $a_1,a_2\in k$ such that $a_1x+a_2y=0\implies a_1=a_2=0$? (Linearity independence)

Can you give for example an example of $k[x,y]$, where $x,y$ is not independent?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even more: [algebraically independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence) variables.

Comment: Linearly independence implies algebraic independence? thanks for your help

Comment: No, e.g. $x$ and $x^2$ are linearly independent but not algebraically independent.

Comment: Backwards: algebraic independence implies linear independence.